# Email between domain and subdomain not working

Tags: email, dns, cloudflare, google-workspace, mx-record

I have two different servers to operate my emails.

- G Suite operates e-mail for **domain.com**
- My shared web hosting service operates e-mail for **sub.domain.com**

It all works when we exchange emails to other domains (gmail.com, yahoo.com, etc...).

BUT when I try to email FROM **sub.domain.com** TO **domain.com** it does not work.

Sending FROM **domain.com** TO **sub.domain.com** works.

Is Google blocking it? I cannot find any blocks on the admin console.

Any clues? I have searched stackoverflow and the internet and can´t find a solution.

DNS is managed by CloudFlare (see screenshot below).

Main domain is **b12filmes.com.br**; sub-domain is **astro.b12filmes.com.br**:

[image: dns records]

EDIT: Posted on Server Vault: https://serverfault.com/questions/1041140/email-between-domain-and-subdomain-not-working/1041142#1041142

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been looking for this answer for weeks. Just after I posted here, a friend of mine gave me the answer:

- As the sub.domain.com email is handled by cPanel and the domain.com is also hosted a the same cPanel server, cPanel  tries to send the e-mail to itself.

Simple solution: on cPanel, go to E-mail Routing, select the domain.com and change the routing to "Remote Mail Exchanger".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a dns record for the "astro" subdomain.

Comment: this record is created, as you can see on the screenshot... anyway, the problem was fixed with email routing

Comment: It's created for the main domain but not for the subdomain. You need to create a new MX records for the subdomain.

Comment: it exists and it is not the issue. see answer below

Comment: Hello I double checkced you don't have mx record for astro.b12filmes.com.br check https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#MX/astro.b12filmes.com.br

Comment: yes there is. AND IT IS NOT THE ISSUE. READ BELOW.